# Save an array Row per Row in one query. How can I do that?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, survey

I'm trying to make a survey using php and mysql but I have a little inconvinient with the code, because when I submit the form with the survey, it only saves the last question of the survey, and It is because of the INPUT name.

here is the code.

DATABASE STRUCTURE.

> "Questions" (idquestion, question)
>
> "Surveys" (idsurvey, idquestion, answers, survey_number)

**config.php**

```
<?php

class Connection{
    
    //variables para los datos de la base de datos
    public $server;
    public $userdb;
    public $passdb;
    public $dbname;
    
    public function __construct(){
        
        //Iniciar las variables con los datos de la base de datos
        $this->server = 'localhost';
        $this->userdb = 'root';
        $this->passdb = '';
        $this->dbname = 'sistema_bss';
        
    }
    
    public function get_connected(){
        
        //Para conectarnos a MySQL
        $con = mysql_connect($this->server, $this->userdb, $this->passdb);
        //Nos conectamos a la base de datos que vamos a usar
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $con);
        
        
    }
    
}

?>
```

**Questions.php**

```
 public function show_questions(){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM questions  Where questionsnumber = 1";
    $this->result = $this->objDb->select($query);
    return $this->result;       
    
}

public function new_survey(){
        
    
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO survey VALUES('',  
        
            '".$_POST["questi"]."', 
            '".$_POST["answer"]."')";
        $this->objDb->insert($query);
                
        
    }
```

**Survey_form.php**

hint: The form it's ok, it execute the query but the problem is, that it only store one question and answer of the survey, instead store all the questions and answers (array's rows) at the time.

```
   <form name="newDona" action="new_survey_exe.php" method="post" value= "">

 <?php
            
            //it calls the function that shows all the questions that are stored in the db
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($survey);
                
            if($numrows > 0){
                
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($survey)){?>
                    
                
                        
                        <td>
                    
                        <?php 
                        
                        
                        echo $row["question"];?></td>
                    
                        
                        
                        
                          <th><select name="answer" >
                
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="yes">yes</option>
                        <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    
                    </select>
                        
                        <tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="SAVE" /></td></tr>
```

I think the problem is the "select" name, maybe because it rewrites the other  questions and answers for every question of the survey so it only stores the last question and answer.

I want to store multiple rows using one form :D

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I use '".$_POST["questi"]."',  in a hidden input to save the IDquestion to the database, do you know how to store every row of the array (every questions and answers) in a single form? maybe can  you explain to me a for loop to do it?

Comment: I don't know what eceryone else is talking about here but it looks like all you have to do is make the `<select>` use an array, like `<select name="answer[]">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike but that I tried your method and it still saving only one item in the array. do you have another idea to save every question and answer using the survey form into the database?

Comment: thanks that is what I want....in your form do you determine a constant for the array because I see '123123' and '345345'?.. also I want to ask if  could you send me the project please ? because I couldn't make it. if you are agree I can give you my email.

Comment: I'm going to update this post with the config class and the databse structure which is for the database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer. Your insert command was not assigning columns, just values:

**USE PDO CONNECTION OUTSIDE OF CLASS**

In your case, if you want to just run sql queries you will want to use the raw format of the DB. That requires two changes in my DBEngine. Where it says `protected   $con;` change it to `public   $con;` then when you want to call any kind of sql statement do as follows:

```
// If the DB is already set don't do this step portion
require_once('includes/classes/dbconnect.php');
$db =   new DBConnect('localhost','sistema_bss','root','');
// Here is where you use the PDO class

$query = $db->con->prepare("SELECT MAX(surveynumber) FROM survey");
$query->execute();

if($query->rowCount()>0) {
        while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

**newsurvey.php**

```
<?php
    // Not sure if this is proper path back to root then back
    //to files, so you'll have to fix that if wrong
    // Include db
    require_once('includes/classes/dbconnect.php');
    // Include questions class
    require_once('apps/survey/classes/questions.php');
    // Create connection
    $con    =   new DBConnect('localhost','sistema_bss','root','');

    // If answers not submitted, show form
    if(!isset($_POST['answer'])) {
            include_once('apps/survey/new.form.php');
        }
    // If answers submitted process the form
    else {
            // Create questions class, forward DB connection
            $objDona = new Questions($con);
            // Run the insert class 
            $objDona->NewSurveyMulti($_POST['answer']);
            $display    =   $con->Fetch("select * from survey");
            print_r($display);
        } ?>
```

**new.form.php**

```
<?php
    // Fetch questions
    $cuestionario   =   $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM questions"); ?>

    <form name="newDona" action="" method="post">
    </table><?php
    // Confirm there are questions being drawn from database
    $numrows        =   (is_array($cuestionario))? count($cuestionario): 0;
    if($numrows > 0) {
            // Loop through questions
            foreach($cuestionario as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <!-- Write the question -->
                <td><?php echo $row["question"];?></td>
            </tr>
            <th>
                <!-- Set the question id -->
                <select name="answer[<?php echo $row['idquestion']; ?>][]">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">yes</option>
                    <option value="no">NO</option>
                </select>
            </th><?php } ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="SAVE" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
    // I'm adding my PDO database because yours is deprecated
    class DBConnect
        {
            public   $con;
            // Create a default database element
            public  function __construct($host = '',$db = '',$user = '',$pass = '')
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          return 0;
                        }
                }

            // Simple fetch and return method
            public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            while($array = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $rows[]   =   $array;
                                }
                        }

                    return (isset($rows) && $rows !== 0 && !empty($rows))? $rows: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                }
        } ?>
```

**questions.php**

```
<?php
        class Questions
            {
                //atributos
                public $nameDono;
                public $objDb;
                public $result;
                public $connect;

                public function __construct($dbconnection){
                        // My PDO connection
                        $this->MyDB     =   $dbconnection;
                    }

                public function NewSurveyMulti($answer = array())
                    {
                        if(!empty($answer)) {
                                foreach($answer as $questi => $value) {
                                        $this->MyDB->Write("INSERT INTO survey (`idquestion`,`answers`) VALUES('".$questi."', '".$value[0]."')");
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                public function mostrar_survey()
                    {
                        $this->result = $this->MyDB->Fetch("SELECT * FROM questions");
                        return $this->result;       
                    }

                public function new_survey()
                    {
                        $this->MyDB->Write("INSERT INTO survey (`idquestion`,`answers`,`surveynumber`) VALUES("'".$_POST["questi"]."','".$_POST["answer"]."','".$_POST["numsurvey"]."')");
                    }  
            } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly, I really appreciate the time you took to help and teaching me how to solve this problem, one more question, would you recommend me a pretty good web site to learn about pdo?

Comment: The php site pretty much tells you everything you need to know about PDO. I find it really easy (overall) to use and once you create a solid seek and return class to get stuff from your database, it's super smooth! Did that code work then??

Comment: alright, I will learn from the php site, yeah it works, but when I tried to use my old mysql sentence for catching the MAX VALUE from a field it sends an error due to incorrect pdo statement, do you know how to transform a deprecated  $result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(surveynumber) FROM survey"); into pdo ?...THIS is the last question Rasclatt I do not want to be annoying asking and asking so many times :) thanks

Comment: I'm reading the update but I have not found the "protected $con" to change it to "public $con"

Comment: That part is in my `DBConnect` class. Just recopy my `DBConnect` class from above or change that line in it.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works perfectly and I'm learning a lot, thanks again to helped me. Blessings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code Rasclatt

**QUESTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php

    class Questions{

        //atributos
        public $nameDono;
        public $objDb;
        public $result;

        public function __construct(){ 

            $this->objDb = new Database();

        }



        public function NewSurveyMulti($answer) {
                    if(!empty($answer)) {
                            foreach($answer as $questi => $value) {
                                    $query = "INSERT INTO survey VALUES('','".$questi."', '".$value."')";
                                    $this->objDb->insert($query);
                                }
                        }
                }


                // I don't know what the class name is but this is how
    // you would apply this method


    //--------------------------------I don't know where I have to put it, the class name is Questions.
     if(isset($_POST['answer']))
         Questions->NewSurveyMulti($_POST['answer']);



                //this functions shows all the questions for the survey
        public function mostrar_survey(){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM questions ";
            $this->result = $this->objDb->select($query);
            return $this->result;       

        }
        }

    ?>
```

**Survey_form.php**

```
 <?php
    require'../class/questions.php';

        $cuestionario= $objBdonar->show_questions();
        $survey= $objBdonar->NewSurveyMulti($answer) ;

     <form name="newDona" action="new_survey_exe.php" method="post">
    </table><?php


    //it calls the function that shows all the questions that are stored in the db
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($cuestionario);
    if($numrows > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cuestionario)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["question"];?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <th>
                <select name="answer[<?php echo $row['questi']; ?>][]">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                </select>
            </th><?php } ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="SAVE" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

**New_survey_exe.php**

```
<?php

require'../class/questions.php';
$objCon = new Connection();
$objCon->get_connected();
$objDona = new Questions();

$objDona->NewSurveyMulti($answer) ;


header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);    

?>
```